# Nservice bus ... Publisher subscriber Filtering subscribers

Tags: c#, nservicebus

I am beginner in Nservice bus 
I have an webapplication and a desktop  windows applicaton 
the web application will publish some events and the desktop windows will subscribe to receive that events.

The windows application  will be installed on multiple different machines
and i imagin that every instance will act as subscriber.

each instance would be used by different user , the user would not be intrested in receiving everything ,he should receive the message only depending on his category .

is it possible to filter the subscribers who should recieve this message before publishing it in case they already subscribed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scenario you are describing is content based routing, not supported in NSB v5.x.

A solution can be to discard of the message in the message handler on the subscriber...